# Can't Install Docker in Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install docker in ubuntu 18.04 with the following command `sudo apt install docker.io`. The problem is that after some stuff is done and it actually starts installing docker I get the following error:

```
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/docker.socket → /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket.
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-11-06 15:24:39 EST; 4ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 6303 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 6303 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

i tried  `systemctl status docker.service` and  `journalctl -xe` but can't figure out the problem as i'm preatty new to linux

**EDIT**

```
systemctl status docker.service output:



 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-11-07 09:18:38 EST; 6s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 2819 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2819 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 07 09:18:38 alejandro-ThinkPad-E480 systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 07 09:18:38 alejandro-ThinkPad-E480 systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Nov 07 09:18:38 alejandro-ThinkPad-E480 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Nov 07 09:18:38 alejandro-ThinkPad-E480 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 07 09:18:38 alejandro-ThinkPad-E480 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 07 09:18:38 alejandro-ThinkPad-E480 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

and `journalctl -xe`

```
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has finished shutting down.
Nov 07 09:18:38 alejandro-ThinkPad-E480 systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has begun shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has begun shutting down.
Nov 07 09:18:38 alejandro-ThinkPad-E480 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has begun starting up.
Nov 07 09:18:38 alejandro-ThinkPad-E480 systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Nov 07 09:18:38 alejandro-ThinkPad-E480 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 07 09:18:38 alejandro-ThinkPad-E480 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 07 09:18:38 alejandro-ThinkPad-E480 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Nov 07 09:18:38 alejandro-ThinkPad-E480 systemd[1]: docker.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
Nov 07 09:19:26 alejandro-ThinkPad-E480 pkexec[2910]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Nov 07 09:19:26 alejandro-ThinkPad-E480 pkexec[2910]: alejandro: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/alejandro] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/u
```

Comment: Can you attach `systemctl status docker.service` and `journalctl -xe` logs too?

Comment: @RuslanGataullin added the logs of those 2 commands

Comment: Khm. I don't see anything here too. Check: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33931 people there have with similar logs and I saw 2 or 3 different solutions as well as cause description. May be it will help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"
sudo apt update
apt-cache policy docker-ce
sudo apt install docker-ce
```

Install docker-compose

```
sudo apt-get install docker-compose
```

if you have non 0 end return err then stop docker servie first

```
systemctl stop docker
```

and start it again after installation of compose

```
systemctl start docker
```

to check if docker is running

```
sudo systemctl status docker
sudo docker run hello-world
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to install Docker on Ubuntu but got the same error as below:

```
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed. 
  docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-01-08 09:41:04 KST; 11ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 3644 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3644 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

"journalctl -xe" doesn't show all messages if user isn't in 'adm' group.

"sudo journalctl -xe" shows the below message:

```
 1월 08 09:41:03 kdndemo-desktop groupadd[3451]: group added to /etc/group: name=docker, GID=999
 1월 08 09:41:03 kdndemo-desktop groupadd[3451]: group added to /etc/gshadow: name=docker
 1월 08 09:41:03 kdndemo-desktop groupadd[3451]: new group: name=docker, GID=999
 1월 08 09:41:03 kdndemo-desktop systemd[1]: Reloading.
 1월 08 09:41:03 kdndemo-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
 1월 08 09:41:03 kdndemo-desktop systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
 1월 08 09:41:03 kdndemo-desktop systemd[1]: Reloading.
 1월 08 09:41:04 kdndemo-desktop systemd[1]: Reloading.
 1월 08 09:41:04 kdndemo-desktop systemd[1]: Reloading.
 1월 08 09:41:04 kdndemo-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
 1월 08 09:41:04 kdndemo-desktop dockerd[3644]: time="2020-01-08T09:41:04.683235561+09:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
 1월 08 09:41:04 kdndemo-desktop dockerd[3644]: failed to load listeners: no sockets found via socket activation: make sure the service was started by systemd
 1월 08 09:41:04 kdndemo-desktop systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 1월 08 09:41:04 kdndemo-desktop systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 1월 08 09:41:04 kdndemo-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

In my case, I solved it by adding a group to my account in /etc/group.

```
sudo:x:27:nini
```